# How does Lumberyard stack up against Unity 5 and UE4?

Tags: lumberyard-engine

Amazon released a new game engine called [Lumberyard](http://aws.amazon.com/lumberyard/) today.

How does it compare to the other two major 3D game engines, Unity and Unreal Engine? What advantages and disadvantages does it have? What can it do that the other two can't do, and vice versa?

Comment: I tried to add a "lumberyard" tag but I don't have enough rep for that.

Comment: This sounds off-topic for this SE (we don't do "which tool is better/worse" here), but it may be on-topic for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not asking "which is better" (which is an opinion), I'm asking "what does X offer over Y"

Comment: That's just "on this feature, is X better than Y?" multiplied across the feature list — still discussion oriented. If all you want is a feature list without 3rd party opinions you can get that off the manufacturers' websites. Since few people have used the engine yet, that's probably your best bet for the moment.

Comment: Its got a long road ahead of it to even be comparable to UE4 atm, technically they are close in the final visual output but making anything in UE4 10x more efficient and generic than lumberyard. Simply put lumberyard is like in day 1 of UE3

Comment: Lumberyard is essentially CryEngine with some Amazon features, so any CryEngine comparison is likely to be valid for Lumberyard.